Time evolution and anti-unitary operators
Let $\hat{H}$ be a system of lattice fermions with two internal states per site, so they can be described using operators $\hat{c}_{m,\alpha}$, with $m$ denoting the lattice site and $\alpha$ the internal state. An anti-unitary operator $\hat{U}$ acts on these operators as
$$\hat{U}\hat c_{m\alpha}\hat{U}^{-1}=\sum_\beta\mathcal U_{\alpha\beta}\hat{c}_{m,\beta}.$$
Since $\hat{U}$ is anti-unitary, it also satisfies that it acts over imaginary scalars as $$\hat{U}i\hat{U}^{-1}=-i.$$
Now suppose that at time $t=0$ I have a state $|\psi(0)\rangle$that is invariant under this transformation, $\hat{U}|\psi(0)\rangle=|\psi(0)\rangle$. Now, I evolve the state with a second-quantized Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\sum_{m,n,\alpha,\beta}\hat{c}_{m\alpha}^\dagger H_{m\alpha,n\beta}\hat{c}_{n\beta}$ that is symmetric under the transformation $\hat{U}$, i.e. $\left[\hat{H},\,\hat{U}\right]=0$. Then I have $$\hat{U}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{U}e^{-i\hat{H}t}|\psi(0)\rangle=\hat{U}e^{-i\hat{H}t}\hat{U}^{-1}\hat{U}|\psi(0)\rangle=e^{+i\hat{H}t}|\psi(0)\rangle\neq|\psi(t)\rangle.$$
Therefore, even though both the initial state and the Hamiltonian are invariant under this transformation, the anti-unitary character makes that any evolved state will break that symmetry. However, this is conceptually a bit strange for me, especially for anti-unitary transformations that have nothing to do with time or time-reversal (for example, sub-lattice symmetry). Since these transformations are used e.g. to classify topological insulators, how can it be that a mere time evolution breaks the symmetry? This has no counterpart for unitary transformations and I don't really get the conceptual meaning of this fact.

But... you are sending $\psi(t) \rightarrow \psi(-t)$.  Isn't that the whole point of time reversal?

I am not thinking now of time reversal, I am considering any antiunitary transformation (e.g. sublattice). Do them all flip the sign of time? What does this mean conceptually for example in the case of sublattice symmetry?

E.g. assume an operator $\hat{O}$ such that $\hat{U}\hat{O}\hat{U}^{-1}=\hat{\tilde{O}}$. Now, $\langle\psi(0)|\hat{O}|\psi(0)\rangle=\langle\psi(0)|\hat{\tilde{O}}|\psi(0)\rangle$ as long as $\hat{U}|\psi(0)\rangle=|\psi(0)\rangle$. However, as soon as you time evolve the state, this stops being true and $\langle\psi(t)|\hat{O}|\psi(t)\rangle\neq\langle\psi(t)|\hat{\tilde{O}}|\psi(t)\rangle$. Now, as I said, if one thinks of this as sublattice symmetry, it is really strange that a mere time evolution breaks it.

In general if $H$ is symmetric under a unitary or anti-unitary transformation $\hat U$, it implies that if $|\psi(t)\rangle$ is a solution to the Schroedinger equation $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle = H|\psi(t)\rangle$, so is $\hat U|\psi(t)\rangle$.  For example, the time reversal operator $T$ is anti-unitary: if a Hamiltonian is symmetric under time reversal, then if $|\psi(t)\rangle$ is a solution to $i\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle = H|\psi(t)\rangle$, then so is $|\psi(-t)\rangle = T|\psi(t)\rangle$.
For anti-unitary symmetries, this implies that if $|E\rangle$ is a stationary state of $H$ with energy $E$ (i.e. $e^{-iHt}|E\rangle = e^{-iEt}|E\rangle$), then $|-E\rangle$ is stationary as well (with energy $-E$), so the spectrum is symmetric about $E=0$.
If the initial state $|\psi\rangle$ maps to itself under $\hat U$, $|\psi\rangle$ can be written as $|\psi_+\rangle + |\psi_-\rangle + |\psi_0\rangle$, where $|\psi_+\rangle$ and $|\psi_-\rangle$ are projections of $|\psi\rangle$ to positive and negative energy states respectively (and $|\psi_0\rangle$ is the remainder), and $\hat U|\psi_\pm\rangle = |\psi_\mp\rangle$, $\hat U|\psi_0\rangle = |\psi_0\rangle$.  Then (letting $H=H_+ + H_- + H_0$, where $H_+=\sum_{E>0}E|E\rangle\langle E|$ and $H_- = \sum_{E<0} E|E\rangle\langle E|$)
\begin{align*}
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt}|\psi\rangle &= e^{-iHt}\Big(|\psi_+\rangle + |\psi_-\rangle + |\psi_0\rangle\Big)\\
&= \Big(e^{-iH_+t}|\psi_+\rangle + e^{-iH_-t}|\psi_-\rangle + |\psi_0\rangle\Big)\\
&= \Big(\hat U e^{iH_+t}\hat U|\psi_+\rangle + \hat U e^{iH_-t}\hat U|\psi_-\rangle + |\psi_0\rangle\Big)\\
&= \Big(\hat U e^{iH_+t}|\psi_-\rangle + \hat U e^{iH_-t}|\psi_+\rangle + \hat U|\psi_0\rangle\Big)\\
&= \hat U\Big(e^{iH_+t}|\psi_-\rangle + e^{iH_-t}|\psi_+\rangle + |\psi_0\rangle\Big)\\
&= \hat U\Big(e^{-iH_-t}|\psi_-\rangle + e^{-iH_+t}|\psi_+\rangle + |\psi_0\rangle\Big)\\
&= \hat U|\psi(t)\rangle
\end{align*}

Ah, I see.  It comes down to the fact that $\hat{U}$ is not linear.  (It is antilinear, duh!).  And it doesn't play well with unitary transformation.
Let's say you define $\hat{U}$ by what it does to the complete set of energy eigenstates.  Normally if $\hat{U}$ is unitary, the phases of these states don't matter.  For antiunitary and antilinear $\hat{U}$, however, you have to specify a precise gauge choice, because a phase factor $e^{i\theta}$ doesn't commute with $\hat{U}$!  Make even a gauge change, and $\hat{U}$ must transform.
More generally, let $\psi_a$ be some second quantized fermion operator with some index $a$, and let the U-transformation be defined by
$$
\hat{U} \psi_a \hat{U}^{\dagger} = J_{ab} \psi_b.
$$
If you make a unitary transformation $\psi_a \rightarrow \tilde{\psi}_a = V_{ab} \psi_b$, the matrix $J$ has to become
$$
J \rightarrow \tilde{J} = V^{*} J V^{\dagger}
$$
so that $\hat{U} \tilde{\psi}_a \hat{U}^{\dagger} = \tilde{J}_{ab} \tilde{\psi}_b$.  Even a mere phase shift of the basis alters $\hat{U}$.
Time evolution is also a unitary transformation.  I guess $\hat{U}$ is, in fact, time dependent.
